# MAX743 unstable with load (5 to +/- 15V)

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter

I have constructed the circuit outlined in the MAX743 datasheet however the negative rail seems to be spiking 8Vs @ roughly 135khz in 15V mode. When I change the chip to 12V mode the spike is reduced to 4V.
I have played around with the capacitor values and found that increasing the capacitors value attached to FB- managed to fix this issue... until I decided to apply a load.

When Applying a load of 470ohm (much less than the maximum load) the whole circuit's voltage drops significantly.

Any suggestions on how I could go about fixing this? I have been trying to get a stable +/- 15V for a around a month now to power an OP-Amp (OP-07x). Could applying only a resistance load make the circuit freak out? Do OP-amps have fancy circuitry inside that prevent this issue from arising in practice?

Thank you for your time everyone! :)

[image: Circuit schematic]

Comment: Did you construct this on a breadboard or a PCB? Did you make sure C1 is very close to the power and ground pins of the IC? Try a balanced load of 1 K ohm on +VO and -VO at the same time. That is only a 15 mA load if set to 15 volt mode. More than most op-amps need.

Comment: @Sparky256 The circuit is currently on a breadboard with the components connecting the side rails. The 5V supply for V+ is coming from a 5V pin on an Arduino Uno. I will try your suggestion now and report back.

Comment: Are you using Schottky diodes?

Comment: You should build this on a generic blank PCB you can buy at Digi-Key, Mouser, etc. Reason is that these high-frequency circuits with sharp rise/fall times treat breadboards like an echo chamber. The friction contacts are much worse than soldering to a copper trace or wire. It is most likely having spurious oscillations giving unstable behavior.

Comment: Maxim applications/EV kits designer here: we offer Evaluation Kits for switching regulators because it CAN'T work on a solderless breadboard. Parasitic inductance ruins the performance. SMPS like this require a good printed circuit board layout. Figure 6 in the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX743.pdf) contains a proven single-layer PCB layout. Note the MAX743 and MAX741 are a pretty old generation, looks like this was before we moved to all surface-mount such as [MAX77231](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/switching-regulators/MAX77231EVKIT.html)

Comment: @vofa I could not find 1n5817 but assume 1n5819 should be fine. We found that using schottky diodes produce more noise than a regular diode rectifier.

Comment: @Sparky256 Would soldering to a vera-board be suitable?

Comment: It was so long ago it might have actually been photo film or vellum... I didn't see an EV kit for this part, just that applications board (probably what the apps engineer used on the road test while writing the datasheet). But you could probably use Eagle and follow the general placement and routing. What matters most on SMPS layouts is minimizing the loop area of the charge and discharge loops, since that minimizes parasitic LC effects.

Comment: @Sparky256 awesome I shall give it a go over the weekend and see if it fixes the issue. Fingers crossed this doesn't create more problems.

Comment: @MarkU Thank you Mark. I think I will need to order one of those MAX77231 EVs to keep this project moving forward just in case my PCB design doesn't work. Is this all I need to buy to power the amp? Unfortunately the chips are $60 here in AUS and I'm running out of budget =/

Comment: I deleted my last comment and turned it into an answer that the OP may be able to do something with.

Answer (score 1):

1) A vector board with 3 holes per pad plus ground and power traces is what I built 90% of all my test fixtures with. It forces you to use DIP and SIP packages but I managed to force-fit a 64 pin PLCC package one time. It was a PITB. Better to use adaptors now days. This 9" x 6" board is about $60 USD.

2) Cut it in half and save the rest for another project. Teaches important lessons before making the big leap to having a board house do a custom board for you.

3) The part number is from Digi-Key. V1019-ND. The part number on the board is 3677 Plugbord. Mfg is Vector Electronics and Technology, inc. Board is 4.5" x 9.6". 0.062 thk with 3-hole solder pads plus wide power and ground traces.

4) You can cut off the plug board end if not needed. Holes are 0.042" diameter and are NOT plated through, so solder both sides when you need to. I had some spares on hand to get the part numbers.

5) Follow the advice of @MarkU and keep caps and Schottky diodes very close to the IC package, as well as the 100uF caps. You can use 1N5817 thru 1N5822, depending on bulk vs. single price.

6) I would use the 1N5822 if possible as it is rated for 50 volts. A 15 volt supply puts 15 volts on the diode output but when the polarity changes the transformer hits it with -16 volts, so the diodes actually have 32 volts p-p across them. The 1N5822 gives you a 40% safety margin.

7) The 100 uF capacitors are supposed to filter out noise, but their leads need to be very short to the IC body. I am surprised that there no filter inductors after the diodes. You can add tiny .1 uF SMD caps across the +VO and -VO lines and ground the caps close to the IC body. A single 100 uF capacitor will not filter out all RF noise due to lead inductance (ESR). A better design (like if you bought a ready made power supply) would have the output inductors and .1 uF caps already installed to meet FCC requirements for noise emission.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will have a go at constructing it today using what you said. Fingers crossed

Comment: I still have a little bit of noise coming out on the negative rail. Is this ok when powering an OP-amp. Do OP-Amps have a regulator inside?

Comment: The 100 uF capacitors are *supposed* to filter out noise, but their leads need to be very short to the IC body. I am surprised that there no filter inductors after the diodes. You can add tiny .1 uF SMD caps across the +VO and -VO lines and ground the caps close to the IC body. A single 100 uF capacitor will not filter out all RF noise due to lead inductance (ESR). A better design (like if you bought a ready made power supply) would have the output inductors and .1 uF caps already installed to meet FCC requirements for noise emission.

Comment: Added paragraph 7 to cover my last comment.

Comment: What are the numbers referring to?

Comment: @immibis. Which numbers? There are many of them in the answer and the comments.

Comment: The numbers in the numbered list.

Comment: @immibis. They make for an easy reference if there is a question about components or their values or wiring. Using 1. xx is also a good way to itemize your paragraphs. You should number or title them if you have a long answer. Olin tends to title his paragraphs by context.